# React - State value sometimes wrong when using Router

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-router, react-state

I am new to React, and I have noticed when sending a state value via Router in `onSubmit`, the value for `spaghetti` in the next page is sometimes wrong.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
const ItalianMenu=()=>{
    const history = useHistory();
    const spaghettiRef = React.createRef();
    const [spaghetti, setSpaghetti] = useState('0');

    useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true; // Will set it to true on mount ...
    return () => { mounted.current = false; }; // ... and to false on unmount
}, []);
const SelectSpaghetti = () => {
   spaghettiRef.current.select();
};

const onSubmit=(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  setButtonDisabled(true);
  setTimeout(()=>{
  
    history.push("/confirmedOrder", {spaghetti, tip});
    setSpaghetti('0')
    setButtonDisabled(false);
    }, 2000) 
} 

return(
    <Grid align="center">
        <Paper style={paperStyle}>
            <Grid align="center">
                <Paper style={italianStyle}>
                    <h2>The Pink Pomodoro</h2>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Grid align="left">
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs={4}>
                            <Typography style={menuItemStyle}>Spaghetti with Meatballs - 
                                <b>$14</b></Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Typography style={menuItemStyle}>Spaghetti with meatballs topped with red marinara sauce.</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2}>
                           <TextField 
                               inputRef={spaghettiRef} 
                               onFocus={SelectSpaghetti}  
                               onChange={(e) => { 
                                   if (mounted.current) {
                                       if (Number(e.target.value) > 10) {
                                           setSpaghetti(10)
                                       } else {
                                           setSpaghetti(e.target.value)
                                       }
                                   }}} 
                                   value={spaghetti}
                                   type='number' 
                                   inputProps={{min: "0", max:"10", style: { 
                                               textAlign: "right", margin:"3px" }}}
                                   fullWidth/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    ...
```

There are **zero results anywhere** about this problem.  Here is my current code for my target component.

```
const ConfirmedOrder=()=>{
      const location = useLocation();
      return(
    
      <Grid>
          <Typography>
              {String(location.state.spaghetti)} {location.state.tip}
          </Typography>
      </Grid>
      );
}
```

So, why would my target component receive incorrect state values from `italianMenu`?